# PHP: file_get_contents from a page using regex h2 tag that is inside a div

Tags: php, html, regex, file-get-contents

This used to work fine to get me a text from a certain web page that exists in a div tag when a user type the id below:

```
function get_text($id) {
  $result = file_get_contents('www.site.net/.$id.'');
  $regex = '/<div class="x">([^<]*)<\/div>/';
  if (preg_match($regex, $result, $matches) && !empty($matches[1])) {   
    return $matches[1]; 
  } else {
    return 'N/A';
  }
}
```

Now the text is more difficult to get, because it's situated here:

```
 <div class="X2">
   <h2 style="font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;">TEXT</h2>
 </div>
```

I tried both div and h2 but it returns me nothing, please help ! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easily solved using PHP's `DOMDocument`:

```
$html = <<<'EOT'
<div class="X2">
 <h2 style="font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;">TEXT</h2>
 </div>
EOT;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$div = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "X2")]')->item(0);
echo $div->textContent;
```

Output:

```
TEXT
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/70sgl)

To fit into your function environment, this should work:

```
function get_text($id) {
    $html = file_get_contents("www.site.net/$id");
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $div = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "X2")]');
    if (count($div)) {
        return $div->item(0)->textContent;
    }
    else {
        return 'N/A';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I replace $doc->loadHTML($html); with url? because I'm getting the text from an other page from an other website

Comment: `$html = file_get_contents($url);` then use the code as is

Comment: I wish you could manage it for me in the first code I gave this is where I'm trying to put it, I'm kinda newbie :( and thank you so much for the help

Comment: @NacereddineAllal see my edit. That should do what you want.